# How can i upload image preivew on github comment

Tags: github, github-api

i want to upload image preview on PR comment not 'drag and drop'
like using github api.
but it seems there is no way.

the way using 'drag and drop' seems using camo hosting by github...
if i link other image link, it shows "Cannot proxy the given URL".

how can i do?